# How can I get the line of an word in a textbox?

Tags: c#, textbox

Can you solve this problem? I don't know how it should work, but maybe you know.

I have two text boxes. In the left one I have this content:

Mo,
28.09.15

Mo,
28.09.15

In the right I want to have the content "English" in the same line like the second "Mo,". Is it possible?

Thank for your help and time.
Dieter

Comment: I don't see any difference between the two lines. What is your input in the left textbox and what is the desired output in the right one?

Comment: The content of the right text box is: Mo, 28.09.15 \n Di, 29.09.15

Comment: And what content would you like?

Comment: I want to get the line of Di, 29.09.15 (in the end there are more lines, only two for example). Then I want to write in the same line like di... "english"

Comment: That should stand in the second text box.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't get the system how you want the textboxes to be filled yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another basic approach:

```
        List<string> lines = new List<string>(textBox1.Lines);
        for(int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
        {
            // check for some condition
            if (lines[i].StartsWith("Di"))
            {
                // modify the line somehow
                lines[i] = lines[i] + ", " + textBox2.Text;
                break; // optionally break?...or modify other lines as well?
            }
        }
        textBox1.Lines = lines.ToArray(); // update the textbox with the new lines
```

Comment: I assume you figured it out Dieter?  Here is the [TextBox.Lines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

you can retrieve the values in the textbox

```
 TextBox objTextBox = (TextBox)sender;
    string theText = objTextBox.Text;
```

or

```
if(sender is TextBox) {
 var text = (sender as TextBox).Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This adds "English" in front of "Di".  I think this is what you are asking.

```
        string text = textBox2.Text;
        text = text.Insert(text.IndexOf("Di"), "English ");
        textBox2.Text = text;
```

But if you are using dates and trying to format them according to region, then you should look into the DateTime class.